# Definition of simple linear algebraic group

Tags: definition, algebraic-groups

Why is it that many sources define simple (or almost-simple) linear algebraic group to be a connected, *semisimple* linear algebraic group such that every proper connected normal subgroup is trivial? Doesn't semisimplicity follow from the last condition?

Comment: I think this may be a matter of which of the versions of the definitions are used. For one thing, you should probably be assuming all the groups in question to be reduced rather than just connected, or you end up with some examples that people usually do not consider to be simple.

Comment: Well, but if I am working with classical foundations, surely connectedness (or rather irreducibility) should be enough?

Comment: Possibly, but do the sources requiring semisimplicity also work with that setup? Or maybe they want to leave open the possibility of switching to schemes without having to redefine everything.

Comment: I usually go by Humphreys/Springer/Borel, which seem to stick by classical foundations. (None has all that much to say about simple groups, unfortunately.)

Comment: Indeed, the introductory texts are generally set in the context of varieties. Jantzen's book has a lot more to say about simple (and more generally reductive) groups, but that uses schemes is a crucial way.

Comment: Sigh. All I am trying to do is write some quick preliminaries in a set of lecture notes that I'm polishing up for publication, and of course I want to get everything precisely right so that I don't lie to the young.

Comment: A very commendable goal. I am sorry that I don't have a really satisfying answer at hand. I am fairly certain that you are correct that being semisimple should follow from having no non-trivial proper normal connected subgroups (since to get the definition of semisimple, we just add the word "solvable"), but I hesitate to comment too definitively on anything like this where these things can depend to such a large degree on the precise context.

Comment: A friend suggests that the issue may be that, in the definition of "simple", you exclude non-trivial, proper, normal, connected subgroups *defined over your field of definition K*, whereas, in the definition of "semi-simple", you exclude non-trivial, proper, normal, connected, abelian subgroups defined over the algebraic closure of K. Maybe that's it.